# Ajax fileupload into asset folder (Craft 4)

Tags: assets, craft4, upload

I am upgrading a clients website from Craft 2 to Craft 4, and I'm stuck at ajax fileuploads to the CP.

I'm using fileupload.js for this.

In Craft 2 my code looked like this, and I'm struggling to convert this into usable code for Craft 4:

```
$(inputID).fileupload({
    url: "{{ url('actions/assets/uploadFile') }}",
    dataType: 'json',
    formData: [{name:'folderId', value:1}],
    done: function (e, data) {
            if (data.result.fileId) {
                    var fileId = data.result.fileId; //
            }
        }
    },
})
```

I figured out that the correct URL to post to in Craft 4 is "actions/assets/upload" instead of "actions/assets/uploadFile", however this doesn't work and gives me a 400 bad request error with no further explanation.

I'm completely lost and don't know what further steps to take, I've already looked through all possible corners of the internet for a solution.

Comment: Look like you need to pass the CRSF also when uploading the file.

Comment: Tried that and that unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: I test it on my end it is work though, I will share you my code in answer hope it help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test using this code and working.
For uploading there are few thing that needed:

1. user must login and have access to upload to certain volume.
2. The form must have csrf.
3. It require to use json as content type.

```
{{ csrfInput() }}
{{ actionInput('assets/upload') }}
{{ hiddenInput('folderId', 1) }}

<input name="assets-upload" type='file'>
<input type="button" value="Upload Image" onclick="uploadImage()">
```

```
<script>
    function uploadImage() {
        var formData = new FormData($("#imageUploadForm")[0]);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // Replace with your server-side script
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#result").html(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#result").html("Error uploading image.");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works